# Use same Entity multiple times in another Entity

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a Spring Boot server using JPA and Hibernate where there are 2 entities: `Channel` and `Translation`.

The `Channel` entity has two fields (`nameTranslations` and `descriptionTranslations` that should hold the name and description of a channel in 2 languages french and english) which are of type `Translation` as described as follow:

Class `Channel`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANNEL")
public class Channel {
  
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Translation nameTranslations;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Translation descriptionTranslations;

}
```

and

Class `Translation`

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION")
public class Translation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String en;
    
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String fr;

}
```

My issue is: How can I implement the previously described logic so that there are 2 `Translation` fields in the `Channel` class? I have tried it so far using `@OneToOne` annotation, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide ER diagram of the db schema what you want to map.

Comment: Why do you have mapped by in your Channel->Translation mapping? That is telling JPA that there is a 'channel' property in the Channel entity that controls the foreign key - and there isn't. Removing this will have JPA use a default fk definition within the channel table based on the property name, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of mapping you are trying to achieve, but this will work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANNEL")
public class Channel {
  
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Translation nameTranslations;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Translation descriptionTranslations;
}
```

or, if you want the columns on the other entity table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANNEL")
public class Channel {
  
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(mapped="name", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Translation nameTranslations;

    @OneToOne(mapped="description", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Translation descriptionTranslations;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION")
public class Translation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String en;
    
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String fr;

    @OneToOne
    private Channel name;

    @OneToOne
    private Channel description;
}
```

See the [Hibernate ORM documentation for one-to-one associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional).

Comment: That won't work, as there will be no way for JPA to tell which translation is the nameTranslations vs which is the descriptionTranslations. FK needs to be in channel with Translation's side being mapped by channel's side.

Comment: Ah, I've misunderstood the question :-O, I will fix it.

Comment: @Davide All right, I am waiting for your updated answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I'm not sure if you are asking how to map two different association on the same field or how to map two different association on the same entity. Anyway, the mapping in my current answer should be a more common one